# Oracle use memory without any processes

Tags: linux, oracle, memory, process, crash

After Oracle instance crash there is no one running process, but memory still doesn't free.

What need to do in Linux OS/Win?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can compile this program in C to find oracle process memory usage

http://ejemplosprogramacionc.blogspot.com/2013/06/memoria-de-procesos-oracle-sobre.html